# How to separate behavior of one component from the other [Angular]

Tags: html, angular, dom, angular-components

I'm learning Angular. I've created a `datepicker` from the scratch (*why from the scratch is a different story). As you can see I've two date-picker custom component in the same widget. The code is same for both. I just copied and pasted in the same HTML file.

Here is my **monthpicker.component.html**

Note: `dls` is our own library of basic html components like textfields etc. Please Ignore that.

```
....
<div class="dropdown">
  <span>
    <dls-textbox id="upper">
        <input dlsInput [ngModel]="text" placeholder="...">
    </dls-textbox>
  </span>
  <div class="my-table-div dropdown-content">
    <div class="year-div">
        <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="year" value="2019" min="2018" max="2024">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div *ngFor="..." class="my-table">
      <span *ngFor="...">
        <span class="month-name" (click)="onClick(x);">
          {{ x.monthName }} 
        </span>
      </span>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- A TOGGLE SWITCH GOES HERE-->

<!-- THEN SAME DATE PICKER CODE I COPIED BELOW-->
<div class="dropdown">
  ...
</div>
```

But the problem is, dates selected in one calendar is reflected in the later one also.
[image: screenshot]

I tried separating them by changing `id` and `class` also. But still both of them are responding together. I want them to act independently.

Please correct me.

Comment: Looks like its happening because you are binding to the same variables with the `[ngModel]`

Comment: @NicholasK. Ok let me change variables and then try again. I'll let you know. Thanks.

Comment: yes. It worked. Such a silly mistake on my part. Sorry for that. Post this as an answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you are binding two inputs to the same variable with the `[ngModel]`, due to which a change in one gets reflected in the other.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the ngModel value.

```
 <div class="year-div">
        <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="year" value="2019" min="2018" max="2024">
   </div>
```

If you enter the same value for both ngModels it will reflect the other one as well. You need to use different values for each ng-model.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you should clear the dates which you selected with another one. Make "ID" should be different in each compoenent.

Comment: It would be because of binding.. [ngModel] should be different. Also the variable which you are passing to get the dates also should be different.

Comment: This already been answered though, i appreciate your help. thanks